# Nav-tabs don't work on route profile/{name} Laravel

Tags: laravel

I made a profile page in Laravel with something like /profile/{name} and I use a UserController@showProfile:

```
public function showProfile($name)
{
    if(!Cache::has($name))
    {
        if(DB::table('users')->where('name', $name)->exists())
        {
            $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', $name)->get();
            Cache::put($name, $user, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            return view ('error404');
        }
    }

    return view ('user.profile', ['profile_stats' => Cache::get($name)]);
}
```

But nav-tabs don't work if I put /profile/{name}, if I let it just /profile in routes everything works.

This is profile.blade.php with nav-tabs: https://pastebin.com/wzKM8wRd and this https://pastebin.com/XLBKX6Gr is the layout.

Route::get('profile/{name}', 'UserController@showProfile');

Comment: Can you provide us your blade file? And what do you expect as a result? Because that isn't clear. Please edit your question and add that information!

Comment: Can you provide us Route ?

Comment: I edited. I just want nav-tabs to work anything else is fine.
If I put a default $name value, for example $name = 'Victor' and I remove {name} tag from route that profile is shown but nav-tabs don't work I can't switch between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show us content view script: user.profile.blade.php ?

and don't use cache until you make sure that everything works fine.

```
public function showProfile($name)
{
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', $name)->get();

    return view ('user.profile', ['profile_stats' => $user]);
}
```

---

upd

1. any js errors in the browser console?
2. navigation works when url ends with `/profile/` ? maybe you should try `/profile/{name}/`

---

So fix up js errors... and then come back :) looks like your problem with hash navigation isn't laravel issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, problem was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/jquery.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
```

I forgot to put / in front of js/jquery.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/js/jquery.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
```

However thanks for your answers!